# Arguments for the FlashMessenger Helper in the Action Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm writing a custom Helper class by extending Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract. Inside this Helper class I want to make use of FlashMessenger to show messages when needed. I want to discriminate warning, success, and error messages ( no, I'm not a racist ).

In a class which extends `Zend_Controller_Action` I do that something like this, see below.

```
$this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('error' => 'An error occured'));
```

When writing a Helper class, which extends `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract` you can get the Helpername by using the `getActionController()` and `getHelper` methods together. See below.

```
$this->getActionController()->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
```

I want to add the `array('error' => 'An error occured')` as an argument to the FlashMessenger helper inside the getHelper mehod. I was wondering, is it possible to add arguments to the FlashMessenger Helper through getHelper? If not, then how can you work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.devraju.com/php/zend-framework-using-flashmessenger-helper-outside-of-controller/) provides a solution:

> So if anyone wants to set the flash messages from outside of the
>   action controllers, then you should use something like this using
>   Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker class and its static helper
>   getStaticHelper.

```
$flashmessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');  
$flashmessenger->addMessage(array('error' => 'An error occured'));
```

Since `getHelper('FlashMessenger')` returns an instance of `Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_FlashMessenger`, you should be able to do:

```
$this->getActionController()->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage(array('error' => 'An error occured'));
```

Comment: +1 For the good answer, I didn't knew that addMessage() also accepts array data, because the comments in the library of Zend say @param  string $message.